# How do I force showing '+' sign using StringFormat

Tags: c#, wpf, string

Is there a way to force showing the `+` sign in front of positive numbers when using `StringFormat`?

For example:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PercentAgainstBudget, 
                          StringFormat={}{0:0.00}%}" />
```

If `PercentAgainstBudget` is negative I see the `-` sign. But if its positive, it does not. Since this number is an offset, I'd like to force showing `+/-`. I could make a `ValueConverter` but I'm wondering if there's a way to do it through the `StringFormat` property.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The format string can be made of two parts separated by a semicolon. First part is the format of positive numbers, second of negative. You'll want this: +0.0%;-0.0%

```
PS C:\Users\jachymko> '{0:+0.0%;-0.0%}' -f 2.45
+245,0%
PS C:\Users\jachymko> '{0:+0.0%;-0.0%}' -f -2.45
-245,0%
```